# ASP.NET MVC 2 Preview 1 To Preview 2 Migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do you "convert" a current project from one version to another in ASP.NET MVC 2? I'm using Preview 1 but want to move to Preview 2.  I've never known how to do it correctly, and I don't want to re-create a project and go from scratch again with everything I've got preferably.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's how I did it](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/10/05/38476/). If you're very lucky, you installe the preview, recompile, and everything works. But more likely, you'll have to address some of the specific issues in the post I linked.

You should not have to create a new project and move everything over. But if installing the preview and recompiling doesn't "just work," and the issue you are encountering is not discussed in the post I linked above, then it is sometimes worthwhile to create a new project for the sake of comparison. Figure out what part of your own project doesn't work, and compare it to what you see in the "empty" project.

Comment: I use areas lib as described by Phil Haack, preview 2 includes default, in-the-box support for areas so I think that's the only problem I'd really encounter.